# Web interface to allow clients to write and execute conditional statements

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm writing a web-based system using flask with react and redux that needs to have web-based clients write conditional statements that can be saved to a configuration file, but also executed in real time without restarting the server or other services.
Obviously this can be done using `eval()`, but obviously we won't be using that.
Any safe ways to run user conditions that call on live variables to perform calculations?

As an example they might want to perform a standard conditional calculation like:

```
if(a===1 && (b===2 || c===2)){
  //do something
}
```

Where a, b, and c are values that are provided from the server to the client and change dynamically.

---

**UPDATE based on question:**

The server provides real-time updates on alarms monitored by the server. When an alarm changes state - say from no-alarm to in-alarm - it sends the new data to the client.
The client side renders this information as a list of alarms. The list can be filtered easily enough, but one issue is that you can have an alarm flood event where ~1000 alarms all come in simultaneously. You also have a few standard/common events where a particular series of alarms all change to a particular state at the same time and that indicates a particular issue/fault and hence a particular fix.
Each user is unique, so it can;t be a one-size-fits all approach and it would be useful if each user can set some basic rules that determine what message to display based on the value of any combination of alarms and their alarm state. They would use a browser form to select these condition states which they can submit to the server. This will insert a line into thier personal configuration file held on the server so that each time they log in they automatically have access to these calculation.
if an alarm changes state, it is sent to the client, which then automatically performs the calculation in the background to determine if a message needs to be displayed.

Comment: Can you give the real use case behind this abstraction? I.e. what configuration are we talking about? I suspect there may be an alternate solution as this doesn't sound like something that is common practice.

Comment: How about a custom iframe with script run in it?

Comment: The safest way would be to implement a simple parser that can take the condition configurations as text and then convert them to objects in your code that you can use to execute the intent of the text without actually running the supplied code. Id suggest looking into Abstract Syntax Trees and Parser Generators to get started with that route if you choose to go that way!

Comment: Nice idea. I guess the question then is whether `eval()` (or anything similar) is a big issue, or it's OK so long as I really make sure that it's impossible to submit something bad to the `eval()` function? I could just regex any of these strings when they're submitted and also just before they're read into the `eval()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Appears like the best approach is to allow the strings, but to ensure that all strings are parsed through a super well constructed function to remove anything malicious.
I'll probably run this function many times - first on submission, and also just before executing.
If these functions are developed using an interactive GUI of dropdown buttons and auto-fill input fields that constructs the code for the user (i.e. the user doesn't actually write the code), it should be safe enough.